# Что за пользователь в phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Установил phpMyAdmin и заметил, что создался пользователь phpmyadmin
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для чего он нужен? Есть ли риски по безопасности? Можно ли его удалить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это стандартный пользователь pma который работает с базой `phpmyadmin`.

> Для чего нужен?

Хранит некоторые настройки pma, настройки пользователей, закладки и прочие прелести

> Есть ли риски по безопасности?

Имеет доступ только к своей бд в которой не хранятся пароли остальных пользователей MySQL

> Можно ли его удалить?

Да, но из конфига pma тоже придётся удалить иначе будут ошибки. Так же после удаления будет появляться такое сообщение, но его можно отключить.
[image]

[Документация](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#linked-tables) на английском.